# apply search filter to list of table table rows in jsp page coming from db using servlets

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I have list of data coming from db in a web page.Jsp page using servlets.
Its in the table format with  generating dynamically for list of objects picked from db.

I want to apply filter on the result items like a search box where as I type the corresponding rows will only show.
Can it be done using servlets JSP only or need to be done from front end side using jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a UI feature, so you need to use jquery [auto complete](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) feature. for example :

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  appendTo: "#someElem"
});
```